# Validate the uploaded file size with jQuery form validation remote method

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to do a filesize validation as follows. Please see whether this proposal method makes sense or not. This part alone should work.

```
1> After the user selects a file, I check whether the file has suffix as png, gif etc.
$("#myform").validate({
 rules: {
   fieldForUpload: {
     required: true,
     accept: "png|gif"
   }
 }
});
```

2> Then I would like to use aJax method to upload the file to server for validation even before the user clicks the submit button.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#url

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    fieldForUpload: {
      required: true,
      accept: "png|gif"
      remote: "check-filesize.php"
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my questions:

1> Is this method valid?
In other words, can I validate the fieldUpload with "accept" + "remote" together?

2> Can I enforce to validate the "accept" first, then validate the "remote"?

3> How to implement this "remote" method? 
FYI: I knew how to validate whether an email exists on the DB by using remote.
Do I have to gain some different knowledge in order to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use jQuery's `validate` you can by creating this method:

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    // param = size (en bytes) 
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (file name)
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});
```

You would use it:

```
$('#formid').validate({
    rules: { inputimage: { required: true, accept: "png|jpe?g|gif", filesize: 1048576  }
    messages: { inputimage: "File must be JPG, GIF or PNG, less than 1MB" }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a file upload widget?  Normal form validation requires access to the form fields.  It's not possible in most browsers to actually manipulate file upload input fields.

Check out [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), two Flash-based file upload widgets that permit type and file size restrictions *without* sending the file to the server first.

There's also [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/), two jQuery plugins that try to use modern browser features to do the same thing.  Older browsers might not have the same level of support.

Comment: Hello Charles,

If I use Ajax Upload, how do it hook it up with remote in the jQuery Validation Plugin?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to.  The plugin provides it's own rules for validation.  (Further, normal file inputs are very hard to work with in Javascript, so it's very possible that the Validation plugin wouldn't work properly...)

Comment: Hello Charles,
For form validation, I use jQuery Form Validation Plugin. Then for uploading the file, I just use a PHP script. Now, for the Ajax Upload, how can I use it fit my requirement.

Thank you

Comment: By ... implementing it?  Your question is too vague to answer.  Furthermore, I've never actually used the Ajax Upload plugin, it merely came up in a Google search, and I haven't the faintest clue how to use it.  I would highly suggest reading the linked documentation for more help.